# How to read body of a POST request into Android WebView

Tags: android, post, webview, sdk, request

I have to submit a form to an external URL, that provides into my WebView a series of interaction with the user. 
At the end of this process this external service does a redirect to my another URL (that is fake) through a POST call, sending some data that I need to show at the user.

I tried to catch this POST request into the method shouldInterceptRequest, because I have to read data before the load of my fake url starts, but the methods that I can use on a WebResourceRequest object are useless. There is nothing to read the body of this request.

There is another way to catch my data? Any suggestions?

(I already tried the writeinterception project library, but it doesn't work.)

Thanks a lot in advance.